# OpenGL Texture state usage warning:

Tags: c++, opengl

OpenGL spams me error `Severity: GL_DEBUG_SEVERITY_LOW, Source: GL_DEBUG_SOURCE_API, Type: GL_DEBUG_TYPE_OTHER Texture state usage warning: The texture object (1) bound to texture image unit 0 does not have a defined base level and cannot be used for texture mapping.`
 or just segfaults at `glDrawElements`. The cause was by setting up textures for my game engine.

I tried to set `glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);`. Other solutions are nonsense or theoretical. By other solutions I mean similar questions/anwsers to my question.

After painstakenly stripping opengl code out of medium sized game engine here is the code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <glad/glad.h>
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <stb_image.h>
#include <cstring>

#include <stdint.h>
#include <string>

typedef uint64_t uint64;
typedef uint32_t uint32;
typedef uint16_t uint16;
typedef uint8_t uint8;

typedef int64_t int64;
typedef int32_t int32;
typedef int16_t int16;
typedef int8_t int8;

typedef uint32 uint;

typedef uint8 byte;

typedef std::string String;

static const char* SeverityString(GLenum severity)
{
    switch(severity)
    {
        case GL_DEBUG_SEVERITY_HIGH: return "GL_DEBUG_SEVERITY_HIGH";
        case GL_DEBUG_SEVERITY_MEDIUM: return "GL_DEBUG_SEVERITY_MEDIUM";
        case GL_DEBUG_SEVERITY_LOW: return "GL_DEBUG_SEVERITY_LOW";
        default: return "Unkown severity type!";
    }
}

static const char* SourceString(GLenum source)
{
    switch(source)
    {
        case GL_DEBUG_SOURCE_API_ARB: return "GL_DEBUG_SOURCE_API";
        case GL_DEBUG_SOURCE_WINDOW_SYSTEM_ARB: return "GL_DEBUG_SOURCE_WINDOW_SYSTEM";
        case GL_DEBUG_SOURCE_SHADER_COMPILER_ARB: return "GL_DEBUG_SOURCE_SHADER_COMPILER";
        case GL_DEBUG_SOURCE_THIRD_PARTY_ARB: return "GL_DEBUG_SOURCE_THIRD_PARTY";
        case GL_DEBUG_SOURCE_APPLICATION_ARB: return "GL_DEBUG_SOURCE_APPLICATION";
        case GL_DEBUG_SOURCE_OTHER_ARB: return "GL_DEBUG_SOURCE_OTHER";
        default: return "Unkown source type!";
    }
}

static const char* TypeString(GLenum type)
{
    switch(type)
    {
        case GL_DEBUG_TYPE_ERROR_ARB: return "GL_DEBUG_TYPE_ERROR";
        case GL_DEBUG_TYPE_DEPRECATED_BEHAVIOR_ARB: return "GL_DEBUG_TYPE_DEPRECATED_BEHAVIOR";
        case GL_DEBUG_TYPE_UNDEFINED_BEHAVIOR_ARB: return "GL_DEBUG_TYPE_UNDEFINED_BEHAVIOR_ARB";
        case GL_DEBUG_TYPE_PORTABILITY_ARB: return "GL_DEBUG_TYPE_PORTABILITY";
        case GL_DEBUG_TYPE_PERFORMANCE_ARB: return "GL_DEBUG_TYPE_PERFORMANCE";
        case GL_DEBUG_TYPE_OTHER_ARB: return "GL_DEBUG_TYPE_OTHER";
        default: return "Unkown type!";
    }
}

static void APIENTRY GLDebugCallback(GLenum source, GLenum type, GLuint id, GLenum severity, GLsizei length,
                const GLchar *message, const void *userParam)
{
    #if 0
    if (type == GL_DEBUG_TYPE_DEPRECATED_BEHAVIOR || 
        type == GL_DEBUG_TYPE_PERFORMANCE || 
        type == GL_DEBUG_TYPE_UNDEFINED_BEHAVIOR ||
        type == GL_DEBUG_TYPE_PORTABILITY)
    {
        BZ_CORE_WARN("Severity: {0}, Source: {1}, Type: {2}. {3}.", SeverityString(severity), SourceString(source), TypeString(type), message);
    }
    else if (type == GL_DEBUG_TYPE_OTHER)
    {
        BZ_CORE_TRACE("Severity: {0}, Source: {1}, Type: {2}. {3}.", SeverityString(severity), SourceString(source), TypeString(type), message);
    }
    else
    {
        BZ_CORE_ERROR("Severity: {0}, Source: {1}, Type: {2}. {3}.", SeverityString(severity), SourceString(source), TypeString(type), message);
    }
    #else
    printf("Severity: %s, Source: %s, Type: %s %s\n", SeverityString(severity), SourceString(source), TypeString(type), message);
    #endif
}

int main()
{  
    if (!glfwInit())
    {
        printf("Failed to initialize glfw!\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 4);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
    GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(960, 540, 
            "Houston we got a problem", nullptr, nullptr);

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    if (!gladLoadGLLoader((GLADloadproc)glfwGetProcAddress)) {
        printf("Faield to initialzie glad!\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    glEnable(GL_DEBUG_OUTPUT);
    glEnable(GL_DEBUG_OUTPUT_SYNCHRONOUS);
    glDebugMessageCallback(GLDebugCallback, NULL);
    glDebugMessageControl(GL_DONT_CARE, GL_DONT_CARE, GL_DONT_CARE, 0, NULL, GL_TRUE);


    glClearColor(0.2f, 0.3f, 0.8f, 1.0f);

    uint32 vao;
    uint32 vbo;
    uint32 ibo;

    float vertices[] = {
        /* Position */          /* Colors */        /* texture coords */
        -0.5f,  0.5f, 1.0f,     1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,   1.0f, 1.0f,
         0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f,     0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,   1.0f, 0.0f,
         0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,     0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,   0.0f, 0.0f,
        -0.5f, -0.5f, 1.0f,     1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,   0.0f, 1.0f
    };

    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
    glBindVertexArray(vao);

    glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * sizeof(float), (void*)(3 * sizeof(float)));

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(2);
    glVertexAttribPointer(2, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 8 * sizeof(float), (void*)(6 * sizeof(float)));

    uint32 indices[] = { 0, 1, 2, 2, 3, 0 };
    glGenBuffers(1, &ibo);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ibo);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indices) * sizeof(uint32), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    std::string vertexSrc = R"(
        #version 330 core
        #extension GL_ARB_separate_shader_objects : enable

        layout (location = 0) in vec3 in_Position;
        layout (location = 1) in vec3 in_Color;
        layout (location = 2) in vec2 in_TexCoords;

        out vec3 v_Position;
        out vec3 v_Color;
        out vec2 v_TexCoords;

        void main()
        {
            v_Position = in_Position;
            v_Color = in_Color;
            v_TexCoords = in_TexCoords;
            gl_Position = vec4(in_Position, 1.0f);
        }
    )";

    std::string fragmentSrc = R"(
        #version 330 core
        #extension GL_ARB_separate_shader_objects : enable

        layout (location = 0) out vec4 color;

        in vec3 v_Position;
        in vec3 v_Color;
        in vec2 v_TexCoords;

        uniform sampler2D u_Texture1;
        uniform sampler2D u_Texture2;

        void main()
        {
            color = mix(texture(u_Texture1, v_TexCoords), texture(u_Texture2, v_TexCoords), 0.2);
        }
    )";

    uint32 program = glCreateProgram();
    uint32 vs = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    const char* src1 = vertexSrc.c_str();
    glShaderSource(vs, 1, &src1, nullptr);
    glCompileShader(vs);

    int32 result;
    glGetShaderiv(vs, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &result);
    if (result == GL_FALSE)
    {
        int length;
        glGetShaderiv(vs, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &length);
        char* message = new char[length];
        glGetShaderInfoLog(vs, length, &length, message);
        printf("Cannot compile vertex shader!\n");
        printf("%s\n", message);
        delete[] message;
        glDeleteShader(vs);

        return 0;
    }

    uint32 fs = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    const char* src2 = fragmentSrc.c_str();
    glShaderSource(fs, 1, &src2, nullptr);
    glCompileShader(fs);

    glGetShaderiv(fs, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &result);
    if (result == GL_FALSE)
    {
        int length;
        glGetShaderiv(fs, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &length);
        char* message = new char[length];
        glGetShaderInfoLog(fs, length, &length, message);
        printf("Cannot compile fragment shader!\n");
        printf("%s\n", message);
        delete[] message;
        glDeleteShader(fs);

        return 0;
    }

    glAttachShader(program, vs);
    glAttachShader(program, fs);
    glLinkProgram(program);

    int32 linkStatus = 0;
    glGetProgramiv(program, GL_LINK_STATUS, &linkStatus);
    if (linkStatus == GL_FALSE)
    {
        int length = 0;
        glGetProgramiv(program, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &length);

        char* message = new char[length + 1];
        memset(message, 0, length + 1);
        glGetProgramInfoLog(program, length, &length, message);
        glDeleteProgram(program);
        printf("Program failed to link.\n%s", message);
        delete[] message;
        return 0;
    }

    glValidateProgram(program);

    glDetachShader(program, vs);
    glDetachShader(program, fs);

    glDeleteShader(vs);
    glDeleteShader(fs);

    glUseProgram(program);

    stbi_set_flip_vertically_on_load(1);
    int32 width, height, bpp;
    byte* bytes = stbi_load("textures/wall.jpg", &width, &height, &bpp, 4);

    uint32 texture1;
    glGenTextures(1, &texture1);
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture1);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA8, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, bytes);
    glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
    stbi_image_free(bytes);

    stbi_set_flip_vertically_on_load(1);
    bytes = stbi_load("textures/awesomeface.png", &width, &height, &bpp, 4);
    uint32 texture2;
    glGenTextures(1, &texture2);
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture2);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA8, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, bytes);
    glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
    stbi_image_free(bytes);

    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture1);

    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture2);

    glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(program, "u_Texture1"), 0);
    glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(program, "u_Texture2"), 1);

    /* Main loop */
    while(!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {

        glBindVertexArray(vao);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ibo);
        glUseProgram(program);
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture1);

        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture2);

        glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, sizeof(indices) / sizeof(uint32), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, nullptr);

        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
        glUseProgram(0);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
        glBindVertexArray(vao);

        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    /* End */
    glDeleteTextures(1, &texture1);
    glDeleteTextures(1, &texture2);
    glDeleteProgram(program);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &ibo);
    glDeleteBuffers(1, &vbo);
    glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &vao);

    glfwDestroyWindow(window);
    glfwTerminate();
}
```

And how I compile it:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

echo ----------spdlog output----------
cd Dependencies/spdlog
g++ -c ./src/spdlog.cpp -std=c++17 -I./include/ -DSPDLOG_COMPILED_LIB -o ../../bin/spdlog.o
cd ../../
ar rcs ./bin/libspdlog.a ./bin/spdlog.o
rm -rf ./bin/spdlog.o
echo ----------glfw output----------
cd Dependencies/glfw
gcc -c ./src/context.c -fPIC -std=c11 -I./include/ -D_GLFW_X11 -lX11 -lXxf86vm -lXrandr -lXi -o ../../bin/context.o
gcc -c ./src/init.c -fPIC -std=c11 -I./include/ -D_GLFW_X11 -lX11 -lXxf86vm -lXrandr -lXi  -o ../../bin/init.o 
gcc -c ./src/input.c -fPIC -std=c11 -I./include/ -D_GLFW_X11 -lX11 -lXxf86vm -lXrandr -lXi -o ../../bin/input.o
gcc -c ./src/monitor.c -fPIC -std=c11 -I./include/ -D_GLFW_X11 -lX11 -lXxf86vm -lXrandr -lXi -o ../../bin/monitor.o
#gcc -c ./src/vulkan.c -fPIC -std=c11 -I./include/ -D_GLFW_X11 -lX11 -lXxf86vm -lXrandr -lXi -ldl -o ../../bin/vulkan.o
gcc -c ./src/window.c -fPIC -std=c11 -I./include/ -D_GLFW_X11 -lX11 -lXxf86vm -lXrandr -lXi -o ../../bin/window.o
gcc -c ./src/x11_init.c -fPIC -std=c11 -I./include/ -D_GLFW_X11 -lX11 -lXxf86vm -lXrandr -lXi -o ../../bin/x11_init.o
gcc -c ./src/x11_monitor.c -fPIC -std=c11 -I./include/ -D_GLFW_X11 -lX11 -lXxf86vm -lXrandr -lXi -o ../../bin/x11_monitor.o
gcc -c ./src/x11_window.c -fPIC -std=c11 -I./include/ -D_GLFW_X11 -lX11 -lXxf86vm -lXrandr -lXi -o ../../bin/x11_window.o
gcc -c ./src/xkb_unicode.c -fPIC -std=c11 -I./include/ -D_GLFW_X11 -lX11 -lXxf86vm -lXrandr -lXi -o ../../bin/xkb_unicode.o
gcc -c ./src/posix_time.c -fPIC -std=c11 -I./include/ -D_GLFW_X11 -lX11 -lXxf86vm -lXrandr -lXi -o ../../bin/posix_time.o
gcc -c ./src/posix_thread.c -fPIC -std=c11 -I./include/ -D_GLFW_X11 -lX11 -lXxf86vm -lXrandr -lXi -o ../../bin/posix_thread.o
gcc -c ./src/glx_context.c -fPIC -std=c11 -I./include/ -D_GLFW_X11 -lX11 -lXxf86vm -lXrandr -lXi -o ../../bin/glx_context.o
gcc -c ./src/egl_context.c -fPIC -std=c11 -I./include/ -D_GLFW_X11 -lX11 -lXxf86vm -lXrandr -lXi -o ../../bin/egl_context.o
gcc -c ./src/osmesa_context.c -fPIC -std=c11 -I./include/ -D_GLFW_X11 -lX11 -lXxf86vm -lXrandr -lXi -o ../../bin/osmesa_context.o
gcc -c ./src/linux_joystick.c -fPIC -std=c11 -I./include/ -D_GLFW_X11 -lX11 -lXxf86vm -lXrandr -lXi -o ../../bin/linux_joystick.o
cd ../../
ar rcs ./bin/libglfw.a ./bin/*.o
rm -rf ./bin/*.o
echo ----------Glad output----------
cd Dependencies/Glad
gcc -c ./src/glad.c -fPIC -I./include/ -o ../../bin/glad.o
cd ../../
ar rcs ./bin/libglad.a ./bin/glad.o
rm -rf ./bin/glad.o
echo ----------stb_image output----------
cd Dependencies/stb_image
g++ -c ./src/stb_image.cpp -fPIC -I./include -o ../../bin/stb_image.o
cd ../../
ar rcs ./bin/libstbimage.a ./bin/stb_image.o
rm -rf ./bin/stb_image.o

echo ---------- Main.cpp ----------
g++ main.cpp -ggdb -O0 -Wall -pedantic -std=c++17 -L./bin/ -I./Dependencies/glm/include/ -I./Dependencies/spdlog/include/ -I./Dependencies/glfw/include/ -I./Dependencies/Glad/include -I./Dependencies/stb_image/include -lstbimage -lspdlog -lglfw -lglad -lX11 -lXxf86vm -lXrandr -lXi -lGLU -ldl -lz -lpthread -lm -DGLFW_INCLUDE_NONE -o ./bin/Problem
echo ----------End of compile----------
```

I included entire file, because you will be asking me: how is your vertex buffer generated and etc.

Edit: After adding some missing code.
Opengl errors are now `Severity: GL_DEBUG_SEVERITY_LOW, Source: GL_DEBUG_SOURCE_API, Type: GL_DEBUG_TYPE_OTHER Texture state usage warning: The texture object (1) bound to texture image unit 0 does not have a defined base level and cannot be used for texture mapping.` and `Severity: GL_DEBUG_SEVERITY_LOW, Source: GL_DEBUG_SOURCE_API, Type: GL_DEBUG_TYPE_OTHER Texture state usage warning: The texture object (2) bound to texture image unit 1 does not have a defined base level and cannot be used for texture mapping.`

Comment: `glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);` is missing at the begin of the main loop and `glfwSwapBuffers(window);` `glfwPollEvents();` is missing at the end of the main loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems you are misunderstanding what the `sizeof` operator does: It returns the size of the underlying datatype **in bytes**.

```
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 3 * sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

reads definitely out-of-bounds after the first `sizeof(vertices)` bytes. Currently, you try to read three times as many bytes as the vertices array holds. The size parameter should just be `sizeof(vertices)`.

```
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indices) * sizeof(uint32), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

Same here. Replace `sizeof(indices) * sizeof(uint32)` with `sizeof(indices)`.

```
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, sizeof(indices), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, nullptr);
```

This line tries to draw `sizeof(indices) == 6 * sizeof(uint32) == 6 * 4 == 24` vertices. Since your indexbuffer does only contain 6 valid indices, the code segfaults depending on which random data you read with the second problematic line.

The OpenGL messages are just informations. They are less than a warning. They are probably caused because you have an active shader when binding the textures for the first time. Since these textures do not contain any data, OpenGL informs you that they can't be used for sampling.

If you want to get rid of this errors, try to unbind the shader before initializing the textures.

Comment: Still doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: It probably doesn't fix the OpenGL warnings. But it should definitely fix the segfaults.